# FreeBSD 10: Disable ZFS full disk encryption

Tags: freebsd, encryption, zfs

I installed FreeBSD 10.1 and chose to encrypt the ZFS root volume and Swap during install.

I'm now realizing that on the remote KVM vserver I'm on the encryption makes rebooting harder and probably doesn't have the security effect I had in mind when I installed FreeBSD (all disks are decrypted as soon as I enter the passphrase during bootup).

So I'm now thinking of leaving the root volume unencrypted and leave encryption to specific folders / jails and the swap.

Does this make sense?

However I found lots of information about how to enable encryption on FreeBSD but none on disabling it.
Is this even possible? If so: How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there isn't going to be an easy way to disable the encryption because the bits are already encrypted on disk. So a re-install with the encryption disabled may be your only option.

Comment: I decided to just stick with it as the number of reboots will be very limited and (hopefully) only under controlled conditions